# how to show a file chooser dialog in GWT with server-side file system?

Tags: gwt

I have a GWT application, which needs to be configured before it can be used by clients.

I want to show some "perform initial configuration" page and let user select some folder to keep the data in.

now, how do I show a file chooser in the GWT client side which would contain the file system of the server?
I could theoretically implement such a widget myself - read all the files server-side, provide a list to the client, etc, etc. but this looks like a pretty common requirement, so I suspect such a widget should already exist...

Answer (score 0):

GWT does not have an out-of-the-box widget+servlet doing that, and I dont know any 3party library doing that (but maybe you have some success searching in the web).

So you have to create a service in server side to provide the info (folders and files list). In client side I would use a [CellTree](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree) which is very appropriate to display a filesystem structure.